# How are the colors for certain schemes defined in moderncv?

Tags: color, moderncv

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find this information in [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls)...

**There is only written:**

```
% colors
%-------
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% main default color, normally left to black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,0,0}% primary scheme color
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0,0}% secondary scheme color
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,0,0}% tertiary scheme color
```

I think `[rgb]{0,0,0}` is black in every case? What is the difference between `color2` and `color2!50`?

How does it work with those nice grey colors for the first name and the family name letters in the casual-style? And where do I get the hex-codes for those colors?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you use the [`moderncv` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), there is no need to specify a colour scheme. So, by default, the colour scheme is black (or `{rgb}{0,0,0}`). That's what is contained in [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls):

```
% colors
%-------
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% main default color, normally left to black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,0,0}% primary scheme color
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0,0}% secondary scheme color
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,0,0}% tertiary scheme color
```

However, if you choose a specific colour scheme, these colours are (re)defined to be something else.

#### Black / [`moderncvcolorblack.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolorblack.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
```

Actually, nothing new here, but I'm showing it just for completeness.

#### Blue / [`moderncvcolorblue.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolorblue.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
```

#### Green / [`moderncvcolorgreen.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolorgreen.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.35,0.70,0.30}% green
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
```

#### Grey / [`moderncvcolorgrey.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolorgrey.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.55,0.55,0.55}% dark grey
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.55,0.55,0.55}% dark grey
```

#### Orange / [`moderncvcolororange.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolororange.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.95,0.55,0.15}% orange
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
```

#### Purple / [`moderncvcolorpurple.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolorpurple.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.50,0.33,0.80}% purple
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
```

#### Red / [`moderncvcolorred.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvcolorred.sty):

```
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.95,0.20,0.20}% red
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey
```

---

The "tertiary colour scheme" is never used, even though it is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! But where do I get the codes for the pre-specified colors of firstname and familyname? I really like those colors and I want to use them in other documents, too... What font and which size is it?

Comment: @Dave: Inside the `\makecvtitle` macro you'll see the family/last name uses `color2` while the first name uses `color2!50` (50% of `color2`). In your other documents, add `\usepackage{xcolor} \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{X,X,X} \colorlet{color2}{color1!50}` to obtain two colours you can use. Of course, as is shown above, `color1` and `color2` depend on the colour scheme you choose for your CV. The font is the regular Computer Modern font (available by default) and the size is `\namefont` (defined to be `\fontsize{38}{40}\mdseries\upshape` under the `casual` style).

Comment: Aaah, okay, I understood! Thank you very much! I have been looking for the color-codes only inside the black style, and everything there is (0,0,0)... However, the orange style uses different colors. Thanks Werner!

Comment: @Dave: Yes, hence the use of themes, so you don't have to worry about the different colour choices; they have been preselected to look good together.